# MongoDB running as a service, in a container of in a virtual machine

Tags: mongodb, docker

Which solution is generally the best for small to mid size Mongo db instances?
1) Running db as a service?  E.g M-lab, Atlas 
2) Running in Docker container on AWS, Google or Azure 
3) Running db in virtual machine, Linux or Windows

Db size is approx:
15 Gbyte file size 
1M docs 
10K writings and 1M readings per day

We have been running the db in a virtual machine on own hardware for some time. Now we like to move into a cloud based solution and stop worrying about hardware failure.

Comment: Just FYI. When you move to a cloud based solution, you will still be worried about hardware failures. See AWS for [instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html). With a couple of hundred hosts, you will have a couple of events each month.

Answer (score 1):

Running any kind of database in a container is not a great idea. 
I would run it as a normal service in the VM